# Command for finding maximum weight Hamiltonian path between two vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

A [Hamiltonian path](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianPath.html#:%7E:text=A%20Hamiltonian%20path%2C%20also%20called,cycle%20(or%20Hamiltonian%20cycle).) is a graph path between two vertices of a graph that visits each vertex exactly once.
Finding a single Hamiltonian path of a graph $g$ is implemented in the Wolfram Language as [`FindHamiltonianPath[g]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html)

> What command could be used to find the Hamiltonian path with maximum path weight between the starting vertex $s$ and the terminating vertex $t$ in the following edge labeled graph?

[image]

Comment: `FindShortestTour` can also be used as `sp = Last@ FindShortestTour[Graph[edges, EdgeWeight -> (1 - edgeweights)], s,  t]`

Answer (score 3):

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 7, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7, 
   6 <-> 7};
edgeweights = {.5, .5, .7, .3, .6, .7, .6, .4, .8, .7, .6, .7, .8, .8};

graph = Graph[Range[7], edges, 
  EdgeWeight -> edgeweights, 
  EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center],
  EdgeLabelStyle -> 16, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexSize -> Large, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

[image]

```
{s, t} = {1, 7};
```

To find the Hamiltonian path with ***maximum*** path weight, we construct a new graph using `1 - edgeweights` as the setting for `EdgeWeight` and use `FindHamiltonianPath`:

```
hp = FindHamiltonianPath[Graph[edges, EdgeWeight -> (1 - edgeweights)], s, t]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7}
> ```

```
HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph[hp], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

Comment: Does `FindHamiltonianPath` take weights into account at all? The documentation does not suggest so, but then the `Graph` documentation is often incomplete.

Comment: I just tried this: `g = CompleteGraph[4, EdgeWeight -> Reverse@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> Automatic]`  then `FindHamiltonianPath[g]`. The result is the same, regardless of whether I remove `Reverse` or not. This confirms that `FindHamiltonianPath` does not consider weights.

Comment: @Szabolcs, i tried  the example `el = {1 <-> 2, 1<-> 3, 
   1 <-> 4, 2 <->] 3,  3<-> 4}; ew = {0.5, a, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
Graph[el, EdgeWeight -> ew, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]]`. With `a=1` , `FindHamiltonianPath` gives `{4, 3, 2, 1}` and with `a=.1` it gives `{4, 3, 1, 2}` which led me to assume  _"the smallest total **length**"_  meant smallest total _weight_ for weighted graphs. But there is no explicit mention of what _total length_ actually means.

Comment: So it does take weights into account in some way. But in my example from the comment above, I get `{1,2,3,4}` as the output. That's a total weight of 10. {1,4,3,2} would be a total weight of 8, i.e. lower. I am using M12.2. Do you get the same result as me? What am I missing?

Comment: I get the same result `{1,2,3,4}` in both version 11.2.0 and 12.2 (wolfram cloud).

Comment: @Szabolcs,  found a work-around: `g = CompleteGraph[4, EdgeWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> Automatic];
FindHamiltonianPath[WeightedAdjacencyGraph@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@g]` gives
the correct answer `{4, 2, 1, 3}` (total weight 8). And for
`g2 = CompleteGraph[4, EdgeWeight -> Reverse@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> Automatic];`
`FindHamiltonianPath[WeightedAdjacencyGraph@WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@g2]` also gives the correct answer `{1, 3, 4, 2}` (total weight 8).

Comment: There's also a DistanceFunction option which I missed, and may be useful.

Comment: But what does this really do? It adds 0-weight self-loops on each vertex (because of the mismatch between `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` and `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` in their interpretation of zeros). That should not make a difference.

Comment: `Trace` shows that the combination  `DistanceFunction -> Automatic` and `CompleteGraph` always returns the vertex list. A cleaner solution is to use `FindHamiltonianPath[g,  DistanceFunction -> (GraphDistance[g, #, #2] &)]` which gives the correct result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121230/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-kglr).